# state of std::vector after std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, vector, std, exception-safety

I'm trying to find a online reference to see the exception safety of several std containers.

In the case of  `std::vector`, Does it keep the state previous to the push_back call? I would presume the vector has all its objects still valid (no destructors invoked).  What guarantees offer `std::vector` after push_back throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it throws, the vector isn't changed. Even not the `capacity()`.

According to [container.requirements.general]:

> Unless otherwise specified (see 23.2.4.1, 23.2.5.1, 23.3.3.4, and 23.3.6.5) all container types defined in this
>   Clause meet the following additional requirements:
>
> [...]
>
> — if an exception is thrown by a push_back() or push_front() function, that function has no effects.