# Does vector resize throwing bad_alloc invalidate the original data?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers, boost-interprocess

After `std::vector::resize()` throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception, is the original data still valid and accessible in the `std::vector` object?

Does the answer hold for other allocators, e.g. if `boost::interprocess::allocator` is used as the allocator, and `boost::interprocess::bad_alloc` is thrown?

Comment: As per [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize): *If an exception is thrown, this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee).* (I'll let someone with a copy of the standard answer the question)

Comment: I see a possible duplicate now (although the answer wording is specific to `push_back` and `push_front`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899814/state-of-stdvector-after-stdbad-alloc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) is exception safe.

> If an exception is thrown, this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee).

[Link to the exception specification.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize#Exceptions) The specification doesn't mention any particular requirement on the allocator and must hold regardless of the allocator you provide.

Answer (score 3):

> is the original data still valid and accessible in the `std::vector` object?

Yes, `std::vector::resize` has strong exception guarantee (except for the case mentioned as follows). [§26.3.11.3/15 vector capacity [vector.capacity]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.capacity#15):

> If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-CopyInsertable T there are no effects.

The guarantee has nothing to do with what kind of allocator is specified; so it's always true.